# Opening media file in metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

It's giving me a file not found exception? Inside Assets I have "beep.wav" but is not working. 
`visual studio 2012\Projects\Myproject\Myproject\Assets`

```
private async void beep()
{
    MediaElement snd = new MediaElement();
    StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("beep.wav");
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    snd.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
    snd.Play();
}
```

This above code does work, I just need it to add it to the project manually....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your application, `Package.Current.InstalledLocation` won't be the directory your project is located at (visual studio 2012\Projects\Myproject\Myproject\Assets), but rather the directory to which the application gets deployed (it's probably something like `visual studio 2012\Projects\Myproject\Myproject\bin\Debug\AppX\Assets`).

So if you just manually copy the wav file into the Assets directory of your project, it's not going to work, because your application is going to look for it at the deployed location.

You noticed that it worked after you added the wav file to your project, but adding the file to the project is not exactly what made it work. If you add a file to a Windows Store project, and at the file's **Properties** you set the **Build Action** to **Content**, then the file will get copied to the deployed location of your app.

You did not have to manually set the Build Action of this file to Content, because VS automatically does that for certain file types (like wav), thus, the file got copied to the deployed location.

Answer (score 0):

You should access the file stored inside Asset folder using following code

```
 var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/beep.wav"));
```